# Android Volley calling oData using Request.POST giving 403 Error

Tags: android, odata, android-volley

I am calling SAP's oData Service using Volley API from Android and getting HTTP 403 Error for the Request.POST. But for the Request.GET for another Service program is working fine. May I know if there is any issue with my code calling oData Service.

Iam passing MYSAPSSO2 token and CSRF Token obtained from my first request call. But getting Authentication error. Any idea what is missing here?

Same oData POST service using JQUERY/SAPUI5 is working fine without any issues.

```
try {
            /** json object parameter**/
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("SO", so);
            jsonObject.put("STATUS", status);
            jsonObject.put("NET_VALUE", amount);
            Log.i("XXXX", thisMethod+"jsonObject params"+ jsonObject.toString() + "");
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonRespObj) {
                    Log.i("XXXX", thisMethod+"Response from notification service: " + jsonRespObj.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    Log.i("XXXXX", thisMethod+"Error Response: " + volleyError);
                    volleyError.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            ) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    if (mysapsso2 != null) {
                        Log.i("XXX", thisMethod+"MYSAPSSO2 is : " + TokenHandler.getMYSAPSSO2Token());
                        Log.i("XXXX", thisMethod+"X-CSRF-Token is : " + TokenHandler.getCSRFToken());
                        params.put("Cookie", ServiceClass.mysapsso2);
                        params.put("X-CSRF-Token", TokenHandler.getCSRFToken());
                        params.put("contentType", "application/json");
                    }
                    return params;
                }
            };
            queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("XXX", thisMethod+"There was an error => " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("XXXX", thisMethod+"There was an error => " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use StringRequest insted of JsonObjectRequest. Get json encoded response to a string & create json object. Below code work fine for me. try it.

```
public void getPostJsonData() {
        final String URL = "URL";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("server_response");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                fname = JO.getString("firstname"); //or JO.toString()
                                lname = JO.getString("lastname");
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                hashMap.put("Cookie", ServiceClass.mysapsso2.toString);
                hashMap.put("X-CSRF-Token", TokenHandler.getCSRFToken().toString);
                hashMap.put("contentType", "application/json");
                return hashMap;
            }
        };
        final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        requestQueue.addRequestFinishedListener(new RequestQueue.RequestFinishedListener<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void onRequestFinished(Request<Object> request) {
                requestQueue.getCache().clear();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. 1.Should I use getHeaders or getParams to send the Cookie, CSRF and other params ? 2. But I need to send JSON Object in the body /request. can I use getParams / how can I send JSON object?

Comment: getting the same error with String Request too. I tried the Auth cookies with both getHeaders and getParams : W/System.err( 2915): com.android.volley.AuthFailureError
W/System.err( 2915):  at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:159)
W/System.err( 2915):  at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)

Comment: I think our both codes are fine. Problem is in your server side. check 403 error. The 403 Forbidden error is an HTTP status code that means that accessing the page or resource you were trying to reach is absolutely forbidden for some reason. Check your server.